# SPARQL join/ combine the langString values of into one

Tags: sparql

I'm using the geonames dataset and there are two properties `gn:officialName` and `gn:alternateName` which both contain `rdf:langString` values. I hava a CONSTRUCT query where I would like to combine both values into one. Is that possible with SPARQL 1.1?

**Bonus**

How to prioritize the values of one property and only use the other on if there is no translation for a locale available?

Comment: How do you want to "combine both varlues into one"? By concatenation?

Comment: See comment on answer below

Comment: Could you edit that additional information into your answer, please?

Answer (score 0):

You can combine them in the WHERE part of the CONSTRUCT query with a BIND( ... AS ?var) and use ?var in the CONSTRUCT template.

```
BIND ( CONCAT(?v1, ?v2) AS ?var)
```

If ?v1 and ?v2 are different languages, you need to take the `str`

```
BIND ( CONCAT(str(?v1), str(?v2)) AS ?var)
```

and maybe use `strlang` to set the language if you want.

Comment: I don't want to concat them, I want to have the individual langStrings of both I think that's not possible with your answer

Comment: @vanthome it's very unclear what you're after here - your question title says "join/combine langstring values", which is what this anwers provides a solution for (namely combining them by concatentation). If that is not what you meant and you have some other form of "combining" in mind, you should edit your question to clarify this (preferably with a good example).

Comment: If I wanted concatenation I would have asked for it. The question is clear enough, if you understand RDF.

Comment: Please give an example of what you mean by "to combine both values into one".  What output are you after?